# Limiting to a single many-to-many relationship in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

A Paper can have many Authors and an Author can have many Papers. An Author cannot be listed as an Author more than once on the same Paper.

I've set up the many-to-many relationship in Laravel and I am able to use the `attach` method to link Authors to a Paper. However, Laravel allows me to add the same Author twice.

Here is a contrived example.

```
// App\Models\Author
public function papers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany (Paper::class);
}

// App\Models\Paper
public function authors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany (Author::class);
}

// LinkController
public function store (Author $author) {
    $author->papers()->attach (request ("paper")); // works
    $author->papers()->attach (request ("paper")); // adds a second link, should do nothing.
}
```

Obviously I'm hard-coding the second attach above, but users can select the same author twice.

How can I tell Laravel to silently ignore the second request?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the `syncWithoutDetaching` method:

```
// LinkController
public function store (Author $author) {
    $author->papers()->syncWithoutDetaching ([request ("paper")]);
    $author->papers()->syncWithoutDetaching ([request ("paper")]); // does nothing.
}
```

Comment: Or maybe you can use a composite unique index on those two columns in the pivot table so it will prevent even manual addition.

Comment: Doesn't that cause an error when inserting the second row?